# Can unity container register type of internal class?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have create the project and put the Interface and class in the same folder. I'm using Unity container to resolve the interface for object of the class. Now I have another assembly that want to access the assembly about. I don't want anyone to access my class directly. So if it is possible to register type of the internal class it will good for me. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read the How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please add some of your code examples.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* try around with [Friend assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx), but I think it will just cause you problems in the long run.

Instead I would consider two other options.

**Option A**: Use a factory.

Suggested here: [Unity 1.2 Dependency injection of internal types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010612/unity-1-2-dependency-injection-of-internal-types).

```
public class FactoryClass
{
   public IMyInterface CreateInstance()
   {
       return new MyInternalClass(); 
   }
}

internal class MyInternalClass : IMyInterface
{
}
```

Also consider using an public class with an internal constructor, which would force an internal class to create the instance. More information here: [What's the difference between a public constructor in an internal class and an internal constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780801/whats-the-difference-between-a-public-constructor-in-an-internal-class-and-an-i).

```
public class MyAlmostInternalClass // in lack of better name
{
    internal MyAlmostInternalClass() {}
}
```

**Option B**: Reconsider your class completely

Why does it need to be internal? Shouldn't the other assembly use the interface anyway? Make it [sealed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/88c54tsw.aspx) if you don't want anyone the derive from it and don't have any public properties other than the one from the interface it implements. Then there's really no reason to use the class over the interface.